# Visual Studio project to read from Oracle 10 and 11?

Tags: c#, oracle, dll, oracle11g

I have a project that needs to extract data from Oracle.  Problem is that some data comes from Oracle 10 and other's from Oracle 11.

I'm currently including Oracle.DataAccess.dll to my project, but this DLL have to correspond to the version of Oracle.

So can I have 2 Oracle DLL's with the same name to my project?
How can I specify which DLL should be used during each Oracle read?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916855/using-multiple-versions-of-the-same-dll Anyway, are you sure that the latest version of the dll doesn't offer retrocompatibility? I'm currently using Oracle.DataAccess.dll shipped with Oracle client 12.1.0 to access Oracle 11.2.0.2 Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you dont need to have two libraries. The latest version are backward compatible and works fine with Oracle <= 11.

Comment: Thanks - I will give it a try soon.  I'll give the answer the accepted thumbs up if it works!

Comment: You can also connect with Oracle.DataAccess.dll Version 10 to an Oracle Database of version 11g (or 12c)