# MahApps.Metro use Colour.xaml and Color.xam with new versions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, mahapps.metro

I have user control dll which is built with MahApps.Metro 0.1.1 and host app that is trying to use it. The host app is using latest version 1.5.0 of MahApps few years back there was a breaking change in MahApps which was renaming of Colours.xaml to Colors.xaml which is resourcedictionary this is the only thing that is causing the issue . I dont have the code of user control dll so i can't compile it but I still want to use new version of MahApps.Metro in host app. How can I add Colours.xaml to latest version of maha apps so I can use at same time. If I compile Mahapps from source code and add Colours.xaml into it try to use the project starts giving me publickeytoken errors due strongly named assembly.

is there a way to load two different version of same assemblies with different public key token .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916855/using-multiple-versions-of-the-same-dll) how to load multiple versions of the same dll.
2. You can decompile the control dll (if its not protected ) into full project with [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/),then replace the mahApps reference and recompile again.