# Is it possible to use multiple versions of the same library in the project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to use Nest 1.9.2 (which is hardwired to Newtonsoft.Json 9.x) and Puppeteer (requires Newtonsoft.Json 10.x or higher) in the same project.

Nest actually uses a Newtonsoft.Json feature that was removed in 10.x, so I can't just force it.

So, is there a way to use multiple versions of Newtonsoft.Json in the same project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using multiple versions of the same DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5916866/1260204)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using multiple versions of the same DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916855/using-multiple-versions-of-the-same-dll)

Answer (score 3):

**If you talk about referring two versions DLL in one single project**, there is a workaround.  You can refer both nuget packages and then in your driver application (console or web or winform) configuration file, you can add binding redirect to use only one version - as long as your dependencies do not break.

**If you talk about using multiple version DLLs in the same application** then there are 3 ways to do this as specified in [this article.  Although this article](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/referencing-multiple-versions-of-the-same-assembly-in-a-single-application) is for Kentico, it should be able to help you to resolve your query.

**1. Install assembly in GAC**

**2. Custom resolver logic as specified [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916855/using-multiple-versions-of-the-same-dll/5916866#5916866)**

Copying code from that answer to here for ready reference:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
    ...

    static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (/*some condition*/)
            return Assembly.LoadFrom("DifferentDllFolder\\differentVersion.dll");
        else
            return Assembly.LoadFrom("");
    }
```

**3. Using CodeBase in your application's configuration file**

In web.config, you can specify assembly binding redirects.

You can create two folders one for each version and then tell your application to refer that where particular version of a DLL resides.

```
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
         <dependentAssembly>  
            <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"  
                              publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"  
                              culture="neutral" />  

            <codeBase version="1.0.0.0"  
                      href="v1\myAssembly.dll"/>  


            <codeBase version="2.0.0.0"  
                      href="v2\myAssembly.dll"/>  
         </dependentAssembly>  
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

There is another way specified [at this MSDN blog.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2005/11/30/c-2-0-using-different-versions-of-the-same-dll-in-one-application/)

Hope this helps you.