# Sub projects use same dll but different versions within class library project

Tags: c#, dll, reference

I have a class library (A) VS project , which contains two different class library projects (B and C) which both use a dll (D) but of different versions , so

1. A -> B -> Dv1
2. A -> C -> Dv2

All projects and dlls involved are custom so i created strong named dll for D but because A is a class library project, i cant use binding directives in an app.config file (since its not an app)

Does anyone know of a good solution for this?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a search? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916855/using-multiple-versions-of-the-same-dll

Comment: One of the answers on that question suggests [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/11/30/498278.aspx) which looks like it's what you need.

Comment: Those are actually the responses ive looked at. My project **A** is a class library so i cannot use an app.config and since the use of **D** is not in A, but separated to two different sub projects , **B** and **C**, using extern wouldn't help.