# Building against different versions (releases) of third party static libraries (Creo) in one solution

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I would like to create a .net application which works with different versions of Creo. My solution contains two C++ projects that include Creo static libraries. Different versions of Creo libraries are not backward or forward compatible. I would like to create a visual studio application that can create installers which target different versions of Creo. Can I use configuration manager to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to create the corresponding C ++ dlls and then reference them in the C # project.

For how to use different versions of dlls in a project, you can refer to [Using multiple versions of the same DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916855/using-multiple-versions-of-the-same-dll).

As to create `installer`, you can try to use `ClickOnce`. For the steps, you can refer to [How-To: Use ClickOnce to deploy your Applications](https://weblogs.asp.net/shahar/how-to-use-clickonce-to-deploy-your-applications). You just need to add the corresponding dlls to `Application Files` and you can call them after the software installed.

Comment: Thank you @Kyle Wang. Yes, I am planning to create different C++ dlls (from C++ projects in solution) for different versions of Creo and reference them in C# projects. The query is what is the best way to organize it in a single solution of Visual studio? Can I use configuration manager for it? For example, can I create different configurations for different versions of Creo and accordingly change the include files in C++ projects or is there a better way to do it? Thank you in advance.