# Duplicated Newtonsoft.Json package problem in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a project using the Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.5 package, then I wanted to use google.apis.calendar.v3 that installs Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3 automatically which made duplicated on Newtonsoft.Json.

I have tried to uninstall Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.5 but an error occurs:

> Unable to uninstall 'Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.5' because 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.0.0, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.2.0.0, Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.2.0.0, Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.2.1.0, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.2.0.0, PushSharp.2.2.1, WebGrease.1.5.2' depend on it.

What is the best solution to work with google.apis.calendar.v3 and other package that depend on old Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: In the project that references 6.0.5, instead of uninstalling can you upgrade that reference to 12.0.3?

Comment: If you are required to work with both versions, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916855/using-multiple-versions-of-the-same-dll

Comment: I opened Nuget packaged and updated Newtonsoft.Json the latest package and error occour "the package Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.5 failed to uninstall please restart vs to finish process" when I make restart the solution restart and when Ia make rebuild error occour 
"Error CS0433 The type 'JsonConvert' exists in both 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' and 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'