# Using multiple versions of same DLL

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I've run into a situation where an application has multiple (incompatible) versions of one or more dll.

```
app.exe
a.dll                // v3.0
...
plugins/foo/foo.dll
plugins/foo/a.dll    // v4.0
plugins/foo/...
```

In this example, `app.exe` depends on `a.dll` v3.0 and `foo.dll` depends on `a.dll` v4.0. Due to the [search order of `LoadLibrary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order) the `a.dll` v3.0 next to my exe is loaded first, then since it's already in memory, the later v4.0 is skipped.

Assuming I cannot:

- rename the dependent dll (`a.dll` in this case)
- modify `app.exe` nor `foo.dll` to upgrade/downgrade them to a common `a.dll` version

Is there a way to load multiple versions of the same-named dll to work around this? I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916855/using-multiple-versions-of-the-same-dll) regarding AppDomain but that is for managed C# applications, my use case is a native C++ dll.

Comment: Including the version number in the DLL name is of course indicated here, ask the owner for assistance.  Failing that, you'll have to wrangle [an assembly manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/assembly-manifests).

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant searching around there has now led me down the rabbit hole of [Isolated Applications and Side-by-side Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/isolated-applications-and-side-by-side-assemblies-portal), which at a glance sound promising. I'll do some digging and see if that can solve this use case.

Comment: Yet another rabbit hole are delayed-loaded libraries and notification hooks ([example](http://otb.manusoft.com/2013/01/using-delayload-to-specify-dependent-dll-path.htm)). But must be able to modify something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is an [Activation Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/activation-contexts):

> [*Activation contexts*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/a-sbscs-gly) are data structures in memory containing information that the system can use to redirect an application to **load a particular DLL version**, COM object instance, or custom window version. One section of the activation context may contain DLL redirection information which is used by the DLL loader; another section may contain COM server information. The activation context functions use, create, activate, and deactivate activation contexts. The activation functions can redirect the binding of an application to version-named objects that specify particular DLL versions, window classes, COM servers, type libraries, and interfaces. For more information about the activation context functions and structures, see the [Activation Context Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/activation-context-reference).

`app.exe` can use one Activation Context while loading `a.dll` v3.0, and use another Activation Context while loading `foo.dll` so it uses `a.dll` v4.0 instead.

Raymond Chen posted a blog article, [How can I specify that my DLL should resolve a DLL dependency from the same directory that the DLL is in?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20171011-00/?p=97195), which covers a scenario very similar to yours:

> A customer had a program that loaded two DLLs, let’s call them `A.DLL` and `B.DLL`. Both of those DLLs use a common helper DLL called `C.DLL`. The catch is that the two DLLs want to use *different incompatible versions* of `C.DLL`. The two DLLs `A.DLL` and `B.DLL` reside in separate folders, and each folder has a corresponding copy of `C.DLL`.

Except that his solution uses a manifest-based approach to make the Activation Context of `B.DLL` implicitly handled by the system.  If you can modify `foo.dll` to include a manifest, you can take a similar approach in your situation.  Otherwise, you would have to make `app.exe` create a new Activation Context manually before loading `foo.dll`.