# How to use Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstraction 5.0.0 with Azure Durable Functions

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, microsoft.extensions.logging

I am working with Azure Functions and I am having a problem that involves the NuGet "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions". My solution has been running perfectly fine, but recently I added a dependency which depends on "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions 5.0.0". The project builds fine, but when I run it. the following error appears: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0".

I found some information related to this on a [Github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2304). The suggestions that I found were:

1. Downgrade "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" to version 3.1.0. I can't do this, since I have a third-party dependency that references that same NuGet, but with version 5.0.0.
2. Upgrade to .NET 5.0. I can't do this, since I need to use Durable Functions, and those are not yet supported in Azure Functions with .NET 5.0.

I also tried using multiple versions of that same NuGet, but I got the same error (I tried the approach that is mentioned in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916855/using-multiple-versions-of-the-same-dll)).

Is there any way of solving this problem?

UPDATE:
I created a minimal example in which the issue can be reproduced. It is located [here](https://github.com/AlonsoM45/azure-functions-logging-example). The branch **feature/WithLogging3** runs as expected, but the **feature/WithLogging5** fails with the message "'The host has not yet started". If I enable the option to Break the Debugger with Common Language Runtime Exceptions, I get the error "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified".

It seems that the project only fails when there is an ILogger being injected into a function. For instance, this one (taken directly from Visual Studio 2019 Template for Azure Functions with .NET Core 3.1):

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = name ?? data?.name;

        string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
            ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
            : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }
```

If I remove the injected ILogger (and the line in which the logger is used in the method), then the project runs fine. However, I need to use a logger.

I know that the example I provided does not include a Durable Function, but it reproduces the issue, and it will reproduce even if you add a Durable Function to the project, or if you replace the current function with a Durable Function that takes an injected ILogger.

By the way, if it changes anything, I am using Visual Studio 2019 (Enterprise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue as I got no errors for both .Net Core 3.1 and 6 Versioned Azure Durable Functions Project when installed the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` version `5.0.0`  through following steps.

1. Created two projects of Azure Durable Functions in .Net Core 3.1 and 6.
2. Added the package `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` version `5.0.0` using [dotnet core CLI command](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/5.0.0) in the terminal of VS Code project.

`dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions --version 5.0.0`

And Executed the functions one by one, as the following output shows it is running successfully:

**Azure Durable Functions .Net Core 3.1**
[image]

**Azure Durable Functions .Net Core 6**
[image]

#### Updated Answer:

`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions` version `5.0.0` is added to the minimal example provided to the Azure Function and it is running successfully.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I created a minimal example in which the issue can be reproduced. It is located [here](https://github.com/AlonsoM45/azure-functions-logging-example). The branch **feature/WithLogging3** runs as expected, but the **feature/WithLogging5** fails with the message "'The host has not yet started". If I enable the option to Break the Debugger with Common Language Runtime Exceptions, I get the error "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: I updated my original question with the same info I provided in my last comment, and some additional information.

Comment: Hello @AlonsoMontero, Updated the answer as provided same minimal code in the function with the same version 5.0.0 of the Logging extension package. Please check!

Comment: Hello, I did not manage to make to make this work in my computer with .NET Core 3.1. However, I ended up using .NET 6. (which doesn't break for me when using the nuget for logging). In that sense, you solved my issue, so I have accepted your answer as the solution. Thank you for your help and I am sorry about taking so much time to mark your answer as the correct one.